# Function for a time-independent perturbation in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am studying time independent perturbations in quantum mechanics. In my textbook it states that the first order transition probability from state $a$ to $b$ is proportional to the function

$$F(t, \omega )=\frac{1-cos(\omega t)}{\omega^2} $$

it then remarks that

$$F(t, \omega =0) =t^2/2$$

Can anyone explain why this should be the case?

Comment: expand $cos$ to second order and take the limit $\omega\to0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means by $F(t,\omega=0)$ is actually $\lim_{\omega \to 0} F(t,\omega)$.
This limit is calculated as follows as follows using  L'Hôpital's rule.
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(\omega t)}{{\omega}^2}\\
&=\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac{t \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega}\\
&=\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac{t^2 \cos(\omega t)}{2}\\
&=\frac{t^2}{2}
\end{align*}